# HQL. Intersection of two lists

Tags: java, hibernate

**Update:** look my answer below on how to check if 2 list intersects (both for `@ElementCollection` with string/enums and usual entities list mapped like `@OneToMany`)

I have an entity which contains `@ElementCollection`field with enums.

```
public enum StatusType { 
    NEW, PENDING, CLOSED;
}

@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "status_type", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "my_entity_id")}) 
    @Column(name = "status_type", nullable = false)
    private Set<StatusType > statusTypes = new HashSet<StatusType >();

    ...
}
```

Now I want to get all entities which contains status `NEW` or `PENDING` (or both).

I'm trying to use this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u FROM MyEntity u WHERE u.statusTypes in :statusTypes
```

But I'm getting exception: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No value specified for parameter 9.`

How to properly query on collections and filter by intersections?

Answer (score 4):

Problem solved by adding `JOIN` clause to HQL. Hibernate couldn't implicitly recognize that query needs JOIN clause.  May be it will help someone:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u FROM MyEntity u
LEFT JOIN u.statusTypes statusTypes
WHERE statusTypes in :statusTypes
```

I set the query params like this:

```
query.setParameter( "statusTypes", listOfStatusTypesEnums);
```

It will select rows where at least one element of `listOfStatusTypesEnums` list is present in entity's `statusTypes` property (i.e. if 2 list are intersects in some way).

If you have usual list of entities (which are not `@ElementCollection`, but `@OneToMany` etc), same rule will work as well. Just use like this: `LEFT JOIN u.subEntities subEntities WHERE subEntities.id in :subEntityIds`